# setting element name Rcpp error stack usage

Tags: r, rcpp

In rcpp I want to create characterVector, with the vector variable set as character element

I tried with

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
CharacterVector assignName(){
    CharacterVector rn={"a","b","c"};
    rn.names()=rn;

    return rn;
}

/***R
assignName()
m <- assignName()
m
*/
```

For example i have a CharacterVector rn as a,b,c.
rn should be set : a="a", b="b", c="c"

then in R after the call of this function as :

```
m<-assignName()
```

An error occurr :

```
Error: C stack usage 7969212 is too close to the limit
```

But if i do not assign the function to a variable all works, for example if i do :

```
>assignName()
 a  b  c
"a""b""c"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure why this is the case, but it seems it is not a good idea to use the vector itself as name. You can fix this by using `Rcpp::clone`:

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
CharacterVector assignName(){
    CharacterVector rn={"a","b","c"};
    // original rn.names()=rn;
    rn.names()=clone(rn);

    return rn;
}

/***R
assignName()
m <- assignName()
m
*/
```

Comment: ok in this case work but not work if for example i have a matrix with rowname setted as rownames(m)={"a","b","c"}, if i do in rcpp CharacterVector rn = rownames(matrix) and then rn=clone(rn) return rn it will display the same error

Comment: @matteoantonucci Please update the [mre] in your question to reflect these additional requirements.

Comment: i do now sorry if i do question in comment